# The "InvokePowerShell" task failed unexpectedly when publishing from Visual Studio to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

Recently I copied my project (ASP.NET Core on Visual Studio 2015) to a new computer. Everything is set up except that I can't seem to publish to the existing App Service without getting an "InvokePowerShell" error.

I have tried creating a new publish profile, resetting the publish profile for the App Service on Azure, running Visual Studio as administrator but no good. Anyone kindly have an idea how to solve this?

---

```
Published 1/1 projects successfully
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(408,5): Error MSB4018: The "InvokePowerShell" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Management.Automation.PSSecurityException: AuthorizationManager check failed. ---> System.Management.Automation.Host.HostException: A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message: Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning message. Do you want to run C:\Users\rober\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\willfon\src\willfon\Properties\PublishProfiles\willfon20180423121452 - Web Deploy-publish.ps1?
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface.ThrowPromptNotInteractive(String promptMessage)
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface.PromptForChoice(String caption, String message, Collection`1 choices, Int32 defaultChoice)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSAuthorizationManager.RemoteFilePrompt(String path, PSHost host)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSAuthorizationManager.CheckPolicy(ExternalScriptInfo script, PSHost host, Exception& reason)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSAuthorizationManager.ShouldRun(CommandInfo commandInfo, CommandOrigin origin, PSHost host, Exception& reason)
   at System.Management.Automation.AuthorizationManager.ShouldRunInternal(CommandInfo commandInfo, CommandOrigin origin, PSHost host)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.AsyncResult.EndInvoke()
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.InvokePowerShell.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()

1>Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

---

2-27-2020 And now today it's working. Who knows why.

Comment: Are you still facing the problem? Or you're saying everything is working now?

Comment: It's working now for the moment, thank you. I cannot guess at the reason.